Windows 10 no Icons or Thumbnails or Properties
This morning on restart my Windows 10 system does not display icons on the desktop or in Windows Explorer. In the taskbar, Windows displays a default icon:
enter image description here
So the task bar contains an array of the above icons.
No changes were made by me overnight. I also see that when right-clicking on a device, file, or folder in Windows Explorer, and selecting "Properties", no properties are displayed.
So far I have attempted the following:
Running the following batch file as administrator does nothing (IconCache.db is not rebuilt on restart):
ie4uinit.exe -show
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
attrib -h iconcache_*.db
DEL /A /Q "%localappdata%\IconCache.db"
DEL /A /F /Q "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*"
shutdown /r /t 10

Examining the %localappdata% folder verifies that IconCache.db was NOT rebuilt.
Running the following batch file produced the same (non) results:
ie4uinit.exe -show
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
attrib -h iconcache_*.db
DEL /A /Q "%localappdata%\IconCache.db"
DEL /A /F /Q "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*"
echo F | xcopy /H c:\recentbackup\BackupIconCache.db "%localappdata%\IconCache.db"
shutdown /r /t 10

The difference is forcing the replacement of the icon cache from a backup. After running this, IconCache.db has the same size and creation date as BackupIconCache.db.
Also, no thumbnails are visible, even for graphics (.png, .jpg, and so on) files.
How do I recover my icons and thumbnails?

In the windows registry I deleted (as described in the SuperUser post "Missing icons Windows 10")
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons\29

and all icons, thumbnails, and properties instantly re-appeared.
The side effect is that all icons on the desktop now have the annoying arrow.
